# On delete set default many-to-many field django

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, many-to-many

Whenever a Foreign key relation is created in django, you have an option to set that column to `null`, or `default` using the `on_delete` option. What i want to know is if it is possible to achieve the same thing with ManyToManyField Such that when the referenced column in Model A is deleted from database, the column with the ManyToManyField in Model B is set to default

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there are significant differences between `ForeignKey` and `ManyToManyField`. With `ForeignKey`, a new field is created in the database table to reference another model, while with `ManyToManyField`, no new field is created in the database (you can check this in your database). Instead, a new table is created to manage the relationship between the two models. This means that the `on_delete` argument is not required in ManyToManyField, as it is not a field, but a RelatedManager object that handles the many-to-many relationship in the intermediate table.

If you need more control over the intermediate table between two models in a `ManyToManyField`, you can create a custom intermediate model yourself. By doing this, you can define the fields for the intermediate model and also set the `on_delete` parameter for the foreign keys, for example:

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    model_a = models.ManyToManyField(
        ModelA,
        through='IntermediateModel',
        through_fields=('model_b', 'model_a'),
    )

class IntermediateModel(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: So what if I have Model A, B, C and I want to create two ManyToMany relationship in Model C such that It relates with Model A and B, how do I gou about it using this logic.

Comment: In that case, you will end with two intermediate models, one to relate models C and A and another for models C and B